# Solving system of trig equations using sympy

Tags: python, matlab, sympy

I made a system of equations for an optimization of a pro-link motorcycle into matlab that I'm turning into python code beacuse i need to load it into another software. The matlab code is the following:

```
clc
clear 

Lmono= 320;
Lbielletta=145;
IPS= 16.03;
Pivot= -20;

R1x=(-46.72)-((Pivot)*sind(IPS));
R1y=((180.26)-((Pivot)*cosd(IPS)));
R_1x=(-43.52)-((Pivot)*sind(IPS));
R_1y=((-151.37)-((Pivot)*cosd(IPS)));
R4=60; 
R3=203.727;
Ip=100.1;
eta=36.79;


syms phi o 
eqns = [(Lbielletta)^2 == ((R3*cosd(phi)-R4*sind(o)+R_1x)^2)+((-R3*sind(phi)-R4*cosd(o)-R_1y)^2)

(Lmono)^2 == ((((R3*cosd(phi))-(R4*sind(o))-((Ip*cosd(eta+o)))+(R1x))^2) + (((R3*sind(phi))+(R4*cosd(o))-((Ip*sind(eta+o)))+(R1y))^2))];

[phi ,o]=vpasolve(eqns,[phi o]);
```

I wrote this in python :

```
import math as m

Lb = 145.0
Lm = 320.0
IPS= 16.03;
Pivot= -20.0;
R1x=(-46.72)-((Pivot)*m.sin(IPS))
R1y=((180.26)-((Pivot)*m.cos(IPS)))
R_1x=(-43.52)-((Pivot)*m.sin(IPS))
R_1y=((-151.37)-((Pivot)*m.cos(IPS)))
R4=60.0
R3=203.727
Ip=100.1
eta=36.79

import sympy as sym
from sympy import sin, cos
    
sym.init_printing()
phi,o = sym.symbols('phi,o')
f = sym.Eq(((R3*cos(phi)-R4*sin(o)+R_1x)**2)+((-R3*sin(phi)-R4*cos(o)-R_1y)**2),Lb**2)
g = sym.Eq(((((R3*cos(phi))-(R4*sin(o))-((Ip*cos(eta+o)))+(R1x))**2) + (((R3*sin(phi))+(R4*cos(o))-((Ip*sin(eta+o)))+(R1y))**2)),Lm**2)
print(sym.nonlinsolve([f,g],(phi,o)))
```

But when I run the code it loads for about 30 seconds (in matlab it takes 1-2 seconds) and then returns this:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Administrator/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Administrator/.spyder-py3')
EmptySet
```

EmptySet?

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oscar's answer is "correct", but since you are new to Python there are a few things that you'd want to know.

First, in Matlab you are using `sind` and `cosd` which require the angle in degrees. On the other hand, the trigonometric functions exposed by the `math`, `numpy`, `sympy` modules require the angle to be in radians. Hence, we need to convert `Lb, Lm, ...` to radians.

NOTE: since I don't know the kind of problem you are solving, I have applied the `m.radians` to every number. This is probably wrong: you have to fix it!

Once we are done with that, we can use `nsolve` to numerically solve the system of equation, by providing an initial guess.

```py
import math as m
import sympy as sym
from sympy import sin, cos, lambdify, nsolve, Add

sym.init_printing()
phi,o = sym.symbols('phi,o')

Lb = m.radians(145.0)
Lm = m.radians(320.0)
IPS= m.radians(16.03)
Pivot= m.radians(-20.0)
R1x=m.radians(-46.72)-((Pivot)*m.sin(IPS))
R1y=m.radians(180.26)-((Pivot)*m.cos(IPS))
R_1x=m.radians(-43.52)-((Pivot)*m.sin(IPS))
R_1y=m.radians(-151.37)-((Pivot)*m.cos(IPS))
R4=m.radians(60.0)
R3=m.radians(203.727)
Ip=m.radians(100.1)
eta=m.radians(36.79)
f = sym.Eq(((R3*cos(phi)-R4*sin(o)+R_1x)**2)+((-R3*sin(phi)-R4*cos(o)-R_1y)**2),Lb**2)
g = sym.Eq(((((R3*cos(phi))-(R4*sin(o))-((Ip*cos(eta+o)))+(R1x))**2) + (((R3*sin(phi))+(R4*cos(o))-((Ip*sin(eta+o)))+(R1y))**2)),Lm**2)

print(nsolve([f, g], [phi, o], [0, 0]))
# out: Matrix([[0.560675440923978], [-0.0993239452750302]])
```

Since you are solving an optimization problem and the equations are non-linear, it is likely that there are more than one solution. We can create a contour plot of the two equations: the intersections between the contours represent the solutions:

```py
# convert symbolic expression to numerical functions for evaluation
fn = lambdify([phi, o], f.rewrite(Add))
gn = lambdify([phi, o], g.rewrite(Add))

# plot the 0-level contour of fn and gn: the intersection between
# the curves are the solutions you are looking for
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pp, oo = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:100j, 0:2*np.pi:100j]
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.contour(pp, oo, fn(pp, oo), levels=[0], cmap="Greens_r")
ax.contour(pp, oo, gn(pp, oo), levels=[0], cmap="winter")
ax.set_xlabel("phi [rad]")
ax.set_ylabel("o [rad]")
plt.show()
```

[image]

From this picture you can see that there are two solutions. We can find the other solution by providing a better initial guess to `nsolve`:

```
print(nsolve([f, g], [phi, o], [0.5, 3]))
# out: Matrix([[0.451286281041857], [2.54087384334971]])
```

Comment: I was going to suggest redefining `cosd=lambda d: cos(rad(d))` and `sind=lambda d:sin(rad(d))`. That works and I get a solution from nsolve of (32, -5.7), but Davide_sd's advice is great, especially when it comes to plotting and knowing what you are looking for in terms of solutions.

Comment: Thanks Davide, or Grazie se sei italiano. You solved my problem. Hope you have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SymPy's `nsolve` with an initial guess:

```
In [7]: sym.nsolve([f, g], [phi, o], [0, 0])
Out[7]: 
⎡0.228868116194702⎤
⎢                 ⎥
⎣0.345540167046199⎦
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar, you were reallly helpful!!